# Exception when I start my android app on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to start and debug my app in xamarin forms (android) I get an error and I have no clue what it might be:

> A Java.Lang.RuntimeException was thrown.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Here are all the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfjte.jpg

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: With Xamarin.Forms you need to delve into the inner exceptions to find the real problem. Its a mission, especially on Android, but it is buried in there somewhere.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks. I made a picture with all the notes. Is this correct? http://imgur.com/xBCR2NG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the stack trace you will see exception saying that android allows only one navigation page at a screen.